# Jquery Color Box hangs on all browsers

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have an web-page on clicking on a link Jquery colorbox is opened which populates data via a AJAX call, In all browsers sometimes colorbox hangs out and not data is populated on it, this senerio is appearing very random , not getting the actual cause of this why colorbox hangs and not population data some times.
The only solution in front of me for this problem is I should cancel the request if color box hangs out.
Can you please guide me how can I cancel request when data is not populated.
Thanks In advance

Comment: Hangs? As in your browser screen freezes or just colorbox? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the timout property in your ajax call:

[See jQuery.ajax reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> **timeout**
>   Type: Number
>   Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the
>   request. This will override any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup() [...]

```
$.ajax({
url: "/your_ajax_method/",
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
timeout: 3000, //Set your timeout value
success: function(response) { alert(response); },
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {if(textStatus==="timeout") {  
        alert("timed out"); //Handle the timeout
    } else {
        alert("Another error was returned"); //Handle other error type
    }
}
});​
```